# Has the Super Bowl ever been played on the opening day of the Olympics?

Tags: american-football, history, trivia, olympics

Have the two events ever been simultaneous?

Comment: They aren't on the same day this year.  The Super Bowl will be on Feb 2, and the [Sochi opening ceremonies](http://www.sochi2014.com/en/schedule-and-results) are on Feb 7, although some events start a day earlier on Feb 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this has never happened.

Until 2002, the Super Bowl was always played in January, and the Winter Olympics almost always begins in February.  Now that the Super Bowl is played in February, the events are closer.  Since 2002, the Winter Olympic Opening Ceremonies has been scheduled for a Friday, and the Super Bowl is always scheduled for Sunday.  In addition, since both the Super Bowl and the Olympic Opening Ceremonies are worldwide television events, it is unlikely that they would ever schedule both events for the same day.

This year, with the Super Bowl on February 2, 2014, and the Sochi Opening Ceremonies taking place on February 7, the two events are as close as they have ever been, although they were just as close in 2002, when the two events occurred on February 3 and February 8.

Answer (score 1):

The Olympics open on a Friday and the Super Bowl is on a Sunday, to the answer yo the question as asked is no.

However, we can ask if the Super Bowl has ever been during the Olympics.  Historically the answer was also no, but as the Super Bowl has pushed later this will likely be a regular occurrence.  In particular:

- in 2022 the Super Bowl was on Sunday, February 14 and the (Beijing) Olympics ran from February 4-20.
- in 2026/2030/2034 the Olympics will start on Friday, February 6/8/10; the current NFL season structure has the Super Bowl on the second Sunday of February.  If that holds, in each of those years the Super Bowl will be on the first Sunday of the Olympics.  The 2026 Super Bowl is already scheduled for February 8.

For past dates of Super Bowls and Olympics in winter Olympic years see [this article from NBC Los Angeles](https://www.nbclosangeles.com/news/sports/beijing-winter-olympics/super-bowl-winter-olympics-collide-for-once-in-a-lifetime-day/2819115/) from 2022.  Super Bowl hosts rotate every four years so this will continue.  The 2026 Olympics are in Milan; [2030 is likely to be in France and 2034 in Salt Lake City](https://apnews.com/article/olympics-winter-salt-lake-2030-2034-ioc-e7da1e36b747395f2417b5e8c1d33088).  So in 2026 and 2030 the Super Bowl will be after live Olympic events have ended for the night, but there are likely to be live Olympic events at the same time as the Super Bowl in 2034.